# Automapper - Make IncludeMembers() ignore null

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-10

`IncludeMembers()` will always map from first match even if object is `null`.

Let's say we have the following source models:

```cs
public class Item
{
    public MovieMetadata MovieMetadata { get; set; }

    public BookMetadata BookMetadata { get; set; }
}

public class MovieMetadata
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class BookMetadata
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Destination model:

```cs
public class ItemDetail
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping profile:

```cs
public class ItemProfile : Profile
{
    public ItemProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Item, ItemDetail>()
            .IncludeMembers(
            src => src.BookMetadata,
            src => src.MovieMetadata);

        CreateMap<BookMetadata, ItemDetail>();

        CreateMap<MovieMetadata, ItemDetail>();
    }
}
```

And Program class with instantiation and testing logic:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //create mapper
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddMaps(typeof(ItemProfile));
        });
        var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
        
        //check if configuration valid
        mapper.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        Console.WriteLine("Mapper configuration is valid");
        
        //try map book metadata
        var bookItem = new Item
        {
            BookMetadata = new BookMetadata()
            {
                Title = "book"
            },
            MovieMetadata = null
        };
        var bookItemDetail = mapper.Map<ItemDetail>(bookItem);
        bool isBookCorrectlyMapped = bookItem.BookMetadata.Title == bookItemDetail.Title;
        Console.WriteLine($"Book mapped correctly: {isBookCorrectlyMapped}");
        
        //try map movie metadata
        var movieItem = new Item
        {
            BookMetadata = null,
            MovieMetadata = new MovieMetadata()
            {
                Title = "movie"
            }
        };
        var movieItemDetail = mapper.Map<ItemDetail>(movieItem);
        bool isMovieCorrectlyMapped = movieItem.MovieMetadata.Title == movieItemDetail.Title;
        Console.WriteLine($"Movie mapped correctly: {isMovieCorrectlyMapped}");
    }
}
```

This is the output we will see:

```
Mapper configuration is valid
Book mapped correctly: True
Movie mapped correctly: False
```

We see that mapping for item with `BookMetadata` succeeded, but for `MovieMetadata` failed. Need to make updates so this test succeeds.

Suppose the reason it's failing is because of order of items in `IncludeMembers()`:

```
.IncludeMembers(
            src => src.BookMetadata,
            src => src.MovieMetadata)
```

Here we have `src.BookMetadata` first and `src.MovieMetadata` second. During mapping it will find `Title` field in `src.BookMetadata` and will always use this value even if `src.BookMetadata` is `null`.

Is there any way to skip `src.BookMetadata` if it is `null` and use next `src.MovieMetadata` instead? Or probably need to use something else instead of `IncludeMembers()`?

Here is similar issue: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3204

Code above you can find here to quickly reproduce issue: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9YLGR6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found possible solutions.

### Option 1. IValueResolver

We can create custom value resolver. This solution is good for small amount of fields that we need to map from child objects. As any field will require specific value resolver.

Let's create `TitleResolver`:

```cs
public class TitleResolver : IValueResolver<Item, ItemDetail, string>
{
    public string Resolve(Item source, ItemDetail destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source != null)
        {
            if (source.BookMetadata != null)
            {
                return source.BookMetadata.Title;
            }
            if (source.MovieMetadata != null)
            {
                return source.MovieMetadata.Title;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And update `ItemProfile`:

```cs
public class ItemProfile : Profile
{
    public ItemProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Item, ItemDetail>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Title, opt => opt.MapFrom<TitleResolver>());
    }
}
```

Link to whole code sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6pfKYh

### Option 2. BeforeMap()/AfterMap()

In case if our child objects have more than one field to be mapped to destination object it may be a good idea to use `BeforeMap()` or `AfterMap()` methods.
In that case `ItemProfile` will be updated to:

```cs
public class ItemProfile : Profile
{
    public ItemProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Item, ItemDetail>(MemberList.None)
            .AfterMap((src, dest, ctx) => 
            {
                if (src.BookMetadata != null)
                {
                    ctx.Mapper.Map(src.BookMetadata, dest);
                }
                else if (src.MovieMetadata != null)
                {
                    ctx.Mapper.Map(src.MovieMetadata, dest);
                }
            });

        CreateMap<BookMetadata, ItemDetail>();

        CreateMap<MovieMetadata, ItemDetail>();
    }
}
```

Link to whole code sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ny1yRU